# USB to COM converter for RFID keystrokes

Tags: windows-7, com, usb, rfid

I have been struggling with an RFID reader that is just like a HID keyboard. It takes an ID from a 'swiped' keyfob or card and quickly enters keys into the computer just like a keyboard. As you can see this would cause a variety of problems for someone who wants to use that PC like normal with a keyboard. There would need to be a program that takes thease keystrokes and puts each line of ID's into a database, while a user is still typing away on a regular keyboard without them interfearing with each other.

I have tried very hard to learn about the windows raw input API but to no avail. My basic question is, if I used a USB to COM converter would the keystrokes get sent through thee COM port so I can communicate that way? Which would be a damn site easier that understanding the HID. All answers are greatly appreciated, thank you.

btw, the RFID does this:
1. someone swipes a keyfob or card
2. the RFID reader types in that ID like "178352306"
3. the RFID reader presses the return key
4. loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USB to COM could be an easy solution, but it requires the following:

- The RFID device supports it
- There is a suitable driver for Windows

Only the manufacturer of the device can answer these questions to you.

Actually, the HID keyboard solution has a big advantage: It doesn't require a driver on your host OS. Therefore, it will be functional in any OS and not just Windows.

I would recommend that you create an application to handle the incoming ids. Your application will "consume" the keystrokes from the device and do something useful with it. The user should be advised to use the device only with the application open (not a problem and all) and avoid pressing keys in the normal keyboard, while doing the scanning (it will be good if you had a way to verify that the incoming id is valid).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I can create an application that handles the incomming id's and can just sit it in a background process. I can install the program on the users PC and get it to run on boot. You have actualy hit the nail on the head I believe with your answer, thanks.

Comment: Your application would need to distinguish the input coming from the device and a regular keyboard. Some HID programming would be required. Here is an interesting link http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm

Comment: Oh, I had the impression that because it was comming through the port, I wouldnt have to worry about the RFID as a keyboard, would it not just throw all its traffic down the COM port? Sorry for my ignorance.